# R language: How can I plot scatter plot showing the returns of x against the returns of y? (Quantmod)

Tags: r, scatter-plot, quantmod

I am currently using the quantmod package in R. **I'm trying to get the scatter plot for returns of x against returns of y, however whenever I use the plot function, it shows me a timeseries instead of a scatterplot.**

```
install.packages('quantmod')
library('quantmod')

# set date
from.dat <- as.Date('01/01/2020', format='%d/%m/%y')
to.dat <- as.Date('31/12/2020', format='%d/%m/%y')

# extract data for SPY and VXX 
getSymbols(c('SPY', 'VXX'), from=from.dat, to=to.dat)

# calculate returns
spy <- SPY$SPY.Close
vxx <- VXX$VXX.Close
spy_returns <- diff(log(spy))
vxx_returns <- diff(log(vxx))

# create a matrix containing both SPY and VXX returns
matrix <- merge(spy_returns, vxx_returns)

plot(spy_returns, vxx_returns)
```

I've checked the class of (spy_returns, vxx_returns), they are both xts zoo objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create a scatterplot your data needs to be in vector form. So you need to transform your data from a timeseries to a vector. You can get the data out of a timeseries with the `coredata` function from the zoo package. This package is loaded as soon as you load quantmod or xts.

The line of code below will return a scatterplot that you are looking for.

```
plot(coredata(spy_returns), coredata(vxx_returns)
```

Comment: Thanks! it sure solved the issue. Another way which I found have worked was directly referencing the column ` plot(as.numeric(matrix[, 1]), as.numeric(matrix[, 2]))
`